# Как поменять разрешение на мониторе на Debian 10?

Tags: linux, debian

Не могу настроить разрешение. Нужно 1920x1080 60
В настройках (Settings->Display) нет такого разрешения.

**$ xrandr**

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 400, current 640 x 480, maximum 720 x 480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        0.00* 
   720x400        0.00  
   720x480        0.00
```

**# xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync**

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

**# xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1200x1080_60.00** (  у меня подключен по HDMI ( в меню монитора написано - HDMI)

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find output "HDMI1"
```

**# xrandr --addmode HDMI 1200x1080_60.00**

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find output "HDMI"
```

**$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf**

```
Section "Device"
Identifier   "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier   "Configured Monitor"
  # 1920x1080 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.08 kHz; pclk: 172.80$
  Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  10$
EndSection



Section "Screen"
Identifier   "Default Screen"
Monitor      "Configured Monitor"
Device      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection


  # 1920x1080 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.08 kHz; pclk: 172.80 MHz
  Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
```

**$ cat /etc/default/grub**

```
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
```

**$ xrandr --addmode HDMI 1200x1080_60.00**

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find output "HDMI"
```

Comment: `xrandr: cannot find output "HDMI"` ну да, там же выше пишется что у вашего монитора имя default; 
как вариант попробуйте другим кабелем подключить монитор

Comment: Тупой, но очень важный вопрос: а видеодрайвер-то стоит?)

Comment: @Zt. если других output нет то ни чего не поможет. ставьте драйвер.